# Connecting application to a google store

Tags: android

Now I have my application which reads magazines, books and articles. Now I want to be able to connect to the store from my app and get this items.

> How do I do this?

I am pretty certain people may have already posted this but I just can't seem to write the correct phrase in google to get me to the link.

Comment: what do you mean by connect? publish, submit?

Comment: Well I am trying to get files from the google store and add it to my folder. Sorry for being completely noob about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only accomplish [embeddeding](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/09/embeddable-google-books.html) using the [Google Books API](https://code.google.com/apis/books/) using the [Embedded Viewer API](https://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/viewer/developers_guide.html)

Say: to allow the user to download the book from Google Books in whatever format which could then be stored and read out of your app would surely go against a Policy even if you found a way to do it for free books (I'm guessing). But embedding them seems like fair game.